# content-type: ms-word downloads as .php

Tags: php, dynamic, ms-word, content-disposition

#### Background

I have an application which uses php to print information from a mySQL line, into ms-word...  It was working on another part of my website, but after new implementation... `my browsers seem to want to download the page as an actual document`, rather than give the option to open/save in MS Word... Was wondering if anyone saw an actual problem with the code here...  `No errors are being displayed in my logs, and full error_reporting is on`

#### Code  Excerpt

```
<?php
$id= "1";
$type= "failValidate";

if ($type=="failValidate"){

    $query_letters = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=$id";
    try {
        $letters = $customer->runQuery($query_letters);
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
        foreach($letters as $letter) {
            $filename = "letter.doc";
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=" . $filename);
            echo $letters[0]['letter'];
        }   
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

As of right now, all that happens when I link to run this php script, it gives me an open/save for the actual PHP file...which of course does not have the intended functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to print it without a loop.

```
    $letters = $customer->runQuery($query_letters);
    $filename = "letter.doc";
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
    echo $letters[0]['letter'];
```

Comment: hmmmm, that did it, but *why* would the loop cause it to do so

Comment: The loop may cause multiple header calls and multiple document output if you have more than one letter.